# I get the error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this settings widget (ALREADY FIXED)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

FIXED:
I didn't have a streamprovider set before materialapp

I have this:

```
 final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
  stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData){

      UserData userData = snapshot.data;
```

I have a class of user:

```
class User {

final String uid;
final String email;
final String instagram;
String age;
String gender;
bool account;

User({this.email, this.age, this.gender, this.uid, this.instagram, this.account,});
```

}

I don't know what the problem is, i have used it somewere else and there it is working fine

here the error log:

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this Settings Widget
```

To fix, please:

- Ensure the Provider is an ancestor to this Settings Widget
- Provide types to Provider
- Provide types to Consumer
- Provide types to Provider.of()
- Ensure the correct `context` is being used.

Comment: Can you send the error log, that could be useful information to help you.

Comment: I have updated it with the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have Provider above the Settings widget in the widget tree for this you can pass User class from the provider by wrapping the whole material app with Provider() or just wrap the Settings widget with Provider

```
Provider<User>(
create:(context)=>User(),
child:MaterialApp(
  //app
 ),
),
```

or

```
Provider<User>(
    create:(context)=>User(),
    child:SettingsWidget(
      //app
     ),
    ),
```

Comment: He is just loading and not getting data from it